# Powershell script for cleaning up temp files

Tags: powershell

Currently working on a script that prompts the user to type a machine name in and then Remote-PSSession onto the machine and delete all the temp files.

```
$computer = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the machine name"
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

$tempfolders = @("D:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\*", "D:\Users\*\Downloads\*", "D:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Webex\wbxcache\*", "D:\Users\*\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\*")
Remove-Item $tempfolders -force -recurse
```

All that happens when running the above is it tries to find "D Drive" on the host machine rather than on the expected machine suggesting it doesn't run the Enter-PSSession command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use!**

Use `Invoke-Command` for unattended scripts:

```
$computer = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the machine name"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    $tempfolders = @("D:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\*", "D:\Users\*\Downloads\*", "D:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Webex\wbxcache\*", "D:\Users\*\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\*")
    Remove-Item $tempfolders -Force -Recurse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you can run commands on a remote machine with PowerShell Session.

Please follow this:

Step 1: Create a remote session and store it in a variable:

`$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName server1 -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName domain\username -Message "Enter credentials")`

Step 2: Invoke the commands using below command line:

`Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { <# Commands that you want to run #>  }`

If that command line is supposed to give any output, you can assign it to any variable and use it.